# Can't refresh a php table using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web

I want to refresh a table from the main file of a web page using an ajax function. When the select box change its value the function `dayChanged()` has to be executed. This function is inside the file "ajax.js". The problem is that when I select another option of the elect box nothing happens. I include the file like: `<script src="ajax.js></script>`. I expect to send the value of the select box to a MySQL query (this query is inside "config.php") and then refresh the table of the main file. Here's the main:

```
<html>  
<head> 
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #9C3;
}
p {color:black;}
.table_test {
    font-family: Constantia, Lucida Bright, DejaVu Serif, Georgia, serif;
}
</style>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body><div align='center'>
<div class="table_test">  
  <table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='600' bgcolor='#F6F6F6' bordercolor='#FFFFFF'>  
    <tr>  
      <td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'></td>
      <td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>Festa</td> 
      <td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>Preu</td>  
      <td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>Entrada</td>
      <td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>Final</td>
      <td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>Estil</td>
      <td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>Llista</td>  
    </tr>

<form name="form1" method="post"> 
<div id="table_var">  
<?php
    include ('functions.php');
    $dw = date("w");
    display_table_by_day($dw);
?> 
  </table>    
</div>
<p>Veure un altre dia de la setmana:
  <select name="select_day" id="day_select" onChange="dayChanged()">
    <option value="1">Dilluns</option>
    <option value="2">Dimarts</option>
    <option value="0">Diumenge</option>
  </select>
</p>
</form>
</body>  
</html>
```

The function display_table_by_day($dw) is working right.
The ajax.js file is:

```
function dayChanged()
{
var buscaAjax;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    buscaAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
    buscaAjax = new ActiveXOject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    buscaAjax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(buscaAjax.readyState==4 && buscaAjax.status==200){
            document.getElementById('table_var').innerHTML = buscaAjax.responseText;
            }
        }
        var dato = document.form1.select_day.value;
        buscaAjax.open("GET","config.php?variable="+dato,true);
        buscaAjax.send();
}
```

Finally, the config.php file is:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
include ('connection.php');
include ('functions.php');

$dw = $_GET['variable'];
display_table_by_day($dw);

?>
```

Any idea why is not working?

Comment: is your ajax working correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. How can I check it?

Comment: in mozilla you use firebug , access the console and see what does your ajax return from there

Comment: This is what I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: dayChanged is not defined

Comment: is dayChanged() in ajax.js? double check if your script is linked because the error is dayChanged() is not defined

Comment: Yes it's in ajax.js (I posted the file in the Question). But it's defined as you can see. I don't get what's going on :/

Comment: are you sure, ajax.js is being called? double check it

Comment: I'm using this on main.php: <script src="ajax.js"></script>

Comment: Is this right? Or should I use an include?

Comment: CTRL+U in mozilla (or any browser) and then click the link to your ajax script. if the opened script after you click the link is your ajax, your ajax is well attached, but if it not (such an error message) you did not attach it correctly

Comment: why don't you use jquery? it's easier to use ajax

Answer (score 0):

You  are referencing the `select` by name:

```
var dato = document.form1.select_day.value;
```

Change it to the `id` of the `select` like this:

```
var dato = document.form1.day_select.value;
```

Comment: Thanks, but still nothing happens.

Comment: Try using document.getElementById('day_select').value and make sure it is returning some value.

Comment: It doesn't happen any thing yet. How can I see if it's returning a value? I don't know how to debug in these lenguage (I'm new at it). Thank you.

Comment: console.log(dato); to see in the console or do alert(dato); to see the  value in the alert box.

Comment: I introduec `console.log(dato);` under `var dato = document.form1.('day_select').value;` but I no console pops up and anything happens.

Comment: you dont see console.log in any pop up alert box...you will see that in the console of your browser. In chrome browser go into the tool->developer tools. Or in case you use firefox, to open the Web Console select "Web Console" from the Web Developer submenu in the Firefox Menu.

Comment: Ok. This is what I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: dayChanged is not defined